# If Causing Strange For Loop in MinGW

Tags: c++

When I have an if in a for loop that the compiler cannot optimize out, I get incredibly strange behavior. It appears as though only the passes the loop gets to `a = 0` get run, but there is not early termination in place. An example is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int a = -5; a < 5; a++) {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        //if (rand() % a) {} // uncommenting this line gives the weird results
    }
}
```

When run as above, I get the expected output, this:

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
1
2
3
4
```

However, when I uncomment that line (that has nothing inside the if), I get this output instead:

```
-5
-4
-3
-2
-1
0
```

The for loop appears to be running until it gets to `a = 0`. I only get the second strange result when there is an if (with a body or without), and the optimization setting is `-O0` or `-O1`. I am running MinGW with GCC version 6.3.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: `Floating point exception (core dumped)` occurs when you try to do something impossible with a floating point number, such as divide by zero.

Comment: This is not floating point arithmentic.

Comment: @aguilar "floating point exception" is also reported for integer arithmetic exceptions (don't ask me why)

Comment: If `a` is zero, `x % a` gives undefined behaviour for any `a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is found in the mod operator (`%`) in the `if` statement.

Mod 0 is *undefined behavior* (it's as if you were dividing by zero). So anything goes, anything can happen—there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program. In your case, the loop doesn't continue.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> The binary operator % yields the remainder of the integer division of the first operand by the second (after usual arithmetic conversions; note that the operand types must be integral types). If the quotient a/b is representable in the result type, (a/b)*b + a%b == a. **If the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.** If the quotient a/b is not representable in the result type, the behavior of both a/b and a%b is undefined (that means INT_MIN%-1 is undefined on 2's complement systems)